# File write/read locking mechanism for two processes accessing the same file

Tags: python, c, linux, file, concurrency

I have two processes that need to access the same file.
Process A is a C program that cyclically writes a struct to *file*.

```
int fd = open("file", O_WRONLY);

if (fd >= 0){
    write(fd, &structure, sizeof(structure));
    close(fd);
}
```

Process B is a python program that needs to read the same file and later interpret it using pycstruct.

How can I be sure that process A and process B can access the same file without conflict?

Comment: At least, the call to `write` is atomic. That means that the reader part, provided that it tries to read in a single operation, will see either the value before the write or after, no mix of the values.

Comment: You've got 1 writer process and 1 reader process? You may add a "version number" in the header of the file, version starts with "0". Whenever the writer is about to change the file, it increments the version (i.e. it becomes version 1 on the first access). Then it changes the content and flushes the result. When it' finished, it increments AGAIN the version number (i.e. it becomes 2 after the 1st update). This way, an ODD version number means the writer is currently changing the content of the file ; an EVEN version number, means the file is in a consistent state.

Comment: @Jean-LoupSabatier Your suggestion does not provide any guarantee about the state of the file if the writes and reads are not atomic. By updating the version number "first", then writing updates and then updating the version number "last", you split up the operations, making them non-atomic. Say that the reader has just read the header, and is about to read the data. What's the guarantee that the writer doesn't update the version number and writes some new data? One bit is not going to resolve that problem. You would need double reads, a checksum or hash digest to check for file integrity.

Comment: @Cheatah , the scenario I described is indeed a primitive form of sync, IMO, but if the reader process reads again every time it reads a struct with an odd version from the file (and reads until it gets an even version);  and if, whenever you finish reading your struct from the file, you read again that it's still the same version number than when you first read it, I believe it guarantees the consistency. Though, considering the method a few hours after I wrote it, I realize it is a rather coarse way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an empty file by the writer process may help. During each read operation the file timestamp can be checked. If the timestamp of the file is older than the current read time, read process can read the file content. At the end again the timestamp can be checked to make sure there were no mismatch in the data. If this doesn't workout any IPC  mechanisms needs to be used (shared memory?).